# Centering a variable-size block element on a page

Tags: html, css

I've inherited a very old web page that contains a single paragraph of text centered on the screen, both horizontally and vertically.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<center><table height='100%'>
<tr style="vertical-align:middle"><td>
<pre style="font-size: xx-large">
Q:  How many Bell Labs Vice Presidents does it take to change a light bulb?
A:  That's proprietary information.  Answer available from AT&amp;T on payment
    of license fee (binary only).
</pre>
</td></tr></table></center>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't render properly in jsFiddle, but it does as a standalone page, which you can see [here](https://googledrive.com/host/0B26WWPDYpNnYQ19MRm9aM2VUczg/fortune.html).

I want to bring the markup into the 21st century, while still having the page render basically the same way (in particular, with the text block centered both horizontally and vertically). How can I do this with CSS? A non-table-based solution would be preferable (since the data isn't tabular), but I'll take what I can get.

The new markup I've written for the page looks like this, and has everything except the centering:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>/usr/bin/fortune</title>
    <style>
      p {
        font-size: xx-large;
        font-family: monospace;
        white-space: pre;
      }
      /* insert CSS for centering here */
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Q:   How many Bell Labs Vice Presidents does it take to change a light bulb?
A:  That's proprietary information.  Answer available from AT&amp;T on payment
    of license fee (binary only).</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It renders fine for me in jsfiddle. Just pull the margin for the rendered content all the way to the left and you can see that it centers. [See here](http://i.imgur.com/groMgbw.png).

Comment: It doesn't center vertically in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a good case for `display: table`; you want some table styling for non-tabular data:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <p>
    Q: How many Bell Labs Vice Presidents does it take to change a light bulb? 
    A: That's proprietary information. 
       Answer available from AT&T on payment of license fee (binary only).
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Only centers the content, and does not support IE6 or 7. For just 1 paragraph of text of unknown size, this will keep it centered: http://jsfiddle.net/hXuee/

Comment: This is basically what I wound up doing, except that I applied to container rules to the document body instead of creating a div.

Comment: Sometimes, all you really want is a table-cell :) Credit where credit is due, I first read about this method [on this blog](http://www.hughlashbrooke.com/two-methods-for-vertical-centering-in-css/).

Comment: ...And I wound up having to include the extra div after all because the div-free code, despite working totally fine when I pasted it into Web Inspector, failed when it was actually served from my web server. Browsers are weird sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to adjust it. Here's a way I did that got it pretty much dead center:

```
<html>
<body>
<table height='100%' width='100%'>

<tr style="vertical-align:middle; text-align: center;"><td style="position: relative; top: -6%">
<pre style="font-size: xx-large; ">
Q:  How many Bell Labs Vice Presidents does it take to change a light bulb?
A:  That's proprietary information.  Answer available from AT&T on payment
    of license fee (binary only).
</pre>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit, to center the block and not the text, I used this:

```
<html>
<body>
<table height='100%' style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">

<tr style="vertical-align:middle;"><td style="position: relative; top: -6%;">
<pre style="font-size: xxx-large; ">
Q:  How many Bell Labs Vice Presidents does it take to change a light bulb?
A:  That's proprietary information.  Answer available from AT&T on payment
    of license fee (binary only).
</pre>
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This relies on the text block having a fixed height, which I can do if I have to but would prefer to avoid (the text is dynamically generated and will not always be the same height). Also, `text-align: center` centers each individual line of text; I only want to center the whole block.

Comment: I tried it with different heights and different numbers of lines of text and it stays pretty centered, although it does kind of look off centered during full screen, but when I make the window smaller to check it, it's pretty much dead center. I chose to use a percentage, because I anticipated it might change with a pixel amount.

Comment: Do you mean you want the block to be left aligned internally and centered externally?

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to be left aligned internally; I'm working with what you have now. Where did the 3.7% come from?

Comment: I adjusted it until it centered. The second block of code works for left-aligned internally. I think 6% is actually a better choice. It's based on a percentage of the text, I think, so it should stay centered.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the paragraph tag to have position fixed and then use a percentage for the top attribute to center it on the page.
i did this:

```
position: fixed;
top: 35%;
```

You can check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/MYuqe/